# Jersey 2 + Jackson Annotation / @JsonIgnore

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jersey

> EDIT: Being more specific now i noticed a conflict i want to use BOTH dependencies below:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Basically, I am trying to ignore a property (@JsonIgnore), but none of my Jackson annotations are working. Even the @JsonProperty. I tried to add the @JsonIgnore in getters and setters methods, but same behavior.

I also tried to follow official documentation, and tried different libraries

- import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore; (Same Behavior)
- import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore; (Same Behavior)

I see similar posts like [#12595351](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595351/jersey-jackson-jsonignore-on-setter)

My Response from the Controller, should not display the Revoked. Attribute, but i got this response:

> Actual Response

```
{
    "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJqb2huLmRvZUBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsImlzcyI6ImpvaG4uZG9lQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTI1MzI1Nzk1LCJleHAiOjE1MjUzMzI5OTV9.uri3pRwXQHHG09F-wM40qfuRMRVu_WBK3HlfquGvwYc",
    "expiresAt": "2018-05-03T07:36:35.087Z[UTC]",
    "expiresIn": 7199,
    "issuedAt": "2018-05-03T05:36:35.087Z[UTC]",
    "refreshToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJqb2huLmRvZUBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsImlzcyI6ImpvaG4uZG9lQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTI1MzI1Nzk1LCJleHAiOjE1MjU5MzA1OTV9.xj2oytAVwiAIR8U2upJkPH_BdORuJUNbiicvuvGFz0w",
    "revoked": false,
    "type": "Bearer"
}
```

> Expected Response

```
{
    "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJqb2huLmRvZUBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsImlzcyI6ImpvaG4uZG9lQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTI1MzI1Nzk1LCJleHAiOjE1MjUzMzI5OTV9.uri3pRwXQHHG09F-wM40qfuRMRVu_WBK3HlfquGvwYc",
    "expiresAt": "2018-05-03T07:36:35.087Z[UTC]",
    "expiresIn": 7199,
    "issuedAt": "2018-05-03T05:36:35.087Z[UTC]",
    "refreshToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJqb2huLmRvZUBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsImlzcyI6ImpvaG4uZG9lQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTI1MzI1Nzk1LCJleHAiOjE1MjU5MzA1OTV9.xj2oytAVwiAIR8U2upJkPH_BdORuJUNbiicvuvGFz0w",
    "type": "Bearer"
}
```

> pom.xml (Using Maven)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.wedhany.fimper</groupId>
<artifactId>fimper</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>fimper</name>

<build>
    <finalName>fimper</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.mkammerer</groupId>
        <artifactId>argon2-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-jdk-http</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>Development</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.blocoio</groupId>
                <artifactId>faker</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.7</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.27</jersey.version>
    <springframework.version>4.3.16.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

> Token.java (My Model)

```
package com.wedhany.models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.wedhany.models.enums.token.GrantType;
import com.wedhany.models.enums.token.Type;

import java.util.Date;

public class Token {

/**
 * Attributes
 */
private String accessToken;
private String refreshToken;

@JsonIgnore
private boolean revoked;

@JsonProperty("expires_at")
private Date expiresAt;
private Date issuedAt;

private GrantType grantType;
private Type type;

private User user;

/**
 * @return Token TTL in seconds.
 */
public long getExpiresIn() {
    return this.expiresAt.getTime() < new Date().getTime()
            ? 0
            : (this.expiresAt.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000;
}

/**
 * @return Token that will grant authentication and authorization.
 */
public String getAccessToken() {
    return accessToken;
}

/**
 * @param accessToken Token string.
 */
public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
}

/**
 * @return Token used to request a new token.
 */
public String getRefreshToken() {
    return refreshToken;
}

/**
 * @return Invalid token if true.
 */
public boolean isRevoked() {
    return revoked;
}

/**
 * @param revoked True for invalid.
 */
public void setRevoked(boolean revoked) {
    this.revoked = revoked;
}

/**
 * @param refreshToken Refresh token.
 */
public void setRefreshToken(String refreshToken) {
    this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
}

/**
 * @return Token's expiration date.
 */
public Date getExpiresAt() {
    return expiresAt;
}

/**
 * @param expiresAt Token's expiration date.
 */
public void setExpiresAt(Date expiresAt) {
    this.expiresAt = expiresAt;
}

/**
 * @return Date where the token was requested.
 */
public Date getIssuedAt() {
    return issuedAt;
}

/**
 * @param issuedAt Date where the token was requested.
 */
public void setIssuedAt(Date issuedAt) {
    this.issuedAt = issuedAt;
}

/**
 * @return Type of the token.
 */
public Type getType() {
    return type;
}

/**
 * @param type Type of the token.
 */
public void setType(Type type) {
    this.type = type;
}

/**
 * @return How the token was claimed.
 */
public GrantType getGrantType() {
    return grantType;
}

/**
 * @param grantType Set token type of grant.
 */
public void setGrantType(GrantType grantType) {
    this.grantType = grantType;
}

/**
 * @return Owner of the token
 */
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

/**
 * @param user Token's owner.
 */
public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

> AuthenticationController

```
package com.wedhany.controllers;

import com.wedhany.exceptions.AuthorizationException;
import com.wedhany.models.Token;
import com.wedhany.models.User;
import com.wedhany.services.AuthenticationService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import javax.security.sasl.AuthenticationException;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("auth")
public class AuthenticationController {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

@POST
@Path("login")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response login(User user, @HeaderParam("user-agent") String userAgent) throws Exception {
    try {
        // Authenticate the user using the credentials provided
        this.authenticationService.authenticate(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword());

        // Issue a token for the user
        Token token = this.authenticationService.issueToken(user.getEmail(), userAgent);

        // Return the token on the response
        return Response.ok(token).build();

    } catch (AuthorizationException e) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).build();
    }
}

@POST
@Path("refresh")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response refresh(Token token, @HeaderParam("user-agent") String userAgent) throws AuthenticationException {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED)
            .entity(this.authenticationService.refresh(token.getRefreshToken(), userAgent))
            .build();
}

@POST
@Path("register")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response register(User user) {
    user = authenticationService.save(user);

    return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED)
            .entity(user)
            .build();
}
}
```

Comment: I tried to use @JsonIgnoreProperties over the class. Same thing...

Comment: Adding \@JsonIgnore on property, get ignored in serialisation / deserialisation in spring with Jackson.
Try to add \@JsonIgnore on isRevoked() method in bean. Even this doesn't work, try to add \@JsonIgnoreProperties("revoked") on bean class.
Also you are mixing Jackson 1 with Jackson 2, try to exclude Jackson 1 (or 2) from the dependencies

Comment: @HemantPatel i noticed if i remove the jersey-media-json-binding works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose either one of the following but not both:

```xml
<!-- JSON-B (JSR-347) support -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>
```

```xml
<!-- Jackson 2.x support -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>
```

Both Jackson and JSON-B provide JSON from/to Java binding:

- [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) is a quite mature library for JSON processing. It's flexible and has a fair number of [extensions modules](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson#third-party-datatype-modules).
- [JSON-B](http://json-b.net/) is also referenced as [JSR-347](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=367). It's an specification for JSON binding. The actual implementation will be provided by [Eclipse Yasson](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.yasson), which is the reference implementation of the [JSR-347](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=367).

---

If you want go for [`jersey-media-json-jackson`](https://jersey.github.io/project-info/2.27/jersey/project/jersey-media-json-jackson/dependencies.html), you are supposed to use Jackson [annotations](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/package-summary.html). To ignore a property, for instance, use [`@JsonIgnore`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html).

If you want to go for [`jersey-media-json-binding`](https://jersey.github.io/project-info/2.27/jersey/project/jersey-media-json-binding/dependencies.html), you are supposed to use JSON-B [annotations](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/json/bind/annotation/package-summary.html). To ignore a property, for instance, use [`@JsonbTransient`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/json/bind/annotation/JsonbTransient.html).

---

You are using `jersey-bom`, a *dependency management* artifact that consolidate and centralize the management of dependency versions (without actually adding the dependencies to the project).

So you don't need to specify the version of the `org.glassfish.jersey` artifacts. Use one of the following (without `version`):

```xml
<!-- JSON-B (JSR-347) support -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```xml
<!-- Jackson 2.x support -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22870422/1426227) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2619598/1426227).

Answer (score 1):

Basically the *jersey-media-json-binding* and *jersey-media-json-jackson* have similar behavior. You can't use both at the same time. The reason the jersey-media-json-jackson was not working it is because the provider which have more priority is the jersey-media-json-binding.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me with jackson version 2.8.10

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JsonIgnoreExample {
    private static class BeanWithIgnore {
        @JsonIgnore
        public int id;
        public String name;

        public BeanWithIgnore(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        BeanWithIgnore bean = new BeanWithIgnore(1, "My bean");
        String result = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(bean);
        System.out.println(result); // {"name":"My bean"}
    }
}
```

Comment: If i create a new Project it works, i have problem with this specific one, i just found a conflict between the jersey-media-json-jackson and jersey-media-json-binding. But i really want to use the jersey-media-json-binding.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, I have these libs in my pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${org.glassfish.jersey.core.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- ************** Jackson XML and JSON API ************************* -->          
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>${org.glassfish.jersey.core.version}</version>             
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Just remove that property from your class and add this annotation:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Token {
// ... keep only the properties you want to map
```

this will tell Jackson to only bind the properties which you actually have in your class ignoring all the rest that might be present in the JSON output.

Comment: Same behavior. The output is the same. I don't want to ignoreUnknown, and just to let you know, the @JsonIgnoreProperties are not working since are from same library (com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties). NONE of Annotations from this library are working together with  jersey-media-json-binding

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the whole configuration of your project so one think you can do that is, create manually JSON and then send to response like:

```
ObjectMapper maper = new ObjectMapper();
return Response.ok(maper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(tokenObject));
```

It will work like manual conversion without using auto serialization by Jersey.
Note: This thing is not recommendable but it should work.

You need this dependency for conversion:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```