# Jersey ignoring Jackson annotations

Tags: java, json, jackson, jersey-2.0

I'm working on a Java project that uses Jersey and Jackson to convert Java objects to JSON. A few days ago I noticed that using `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty`to try to change the name of a JSON property had no effect. This issue wasn't that big so I ignored it. Today I created a JPA relationship between to `@Entity` POJOs. The relationship was `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne`. One of the POJOs was being converted to JSON which created an infinite recursion (StackOverflowError). I attached a `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore` annotation to one of the fields but like before this annotation was ignored. I've supplied excerpts of my `pom.xml` which I thought would be relevant based off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50150163/1965453) to a related question.

```
<properties>
    <jackson.version>2.8.7</jackson.version>
    <jersey.version>2.25.1</jersey.version>
    <hk2.version>2.4.0</hk2.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-inhabitant-generator</artifactId>
            <version>${hk2.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate-inhabitants</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<weblogic-application>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</package-name>
        <package-name>com.sun.jersey.*</package-name>
        <package-name>jersey.repackaged.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.glassfish.*</package-name>
        <resource-name>META-INF/services/org.glassfish.hk2.*</resource-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
    <prefer-application-resources>
        <resource-name>META-INF/services/org.glassfish.jersey.*</resource-name>
        <resource-name>org.glassfish.jersey.*</resource-name>
        <resource-name>jersey.repackaged.*</resource-name>
        <resource-name>META-INF/services/org.glassfish.hk2.*</resource-name>
    </prefer-application-resources>
</weblogic-application>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x-transaction</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-simple-http</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-gf-ejb</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-declarative-linking</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-entity-filtering</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-metainf-services</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-mvc</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-mvc-bean-validation</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-mvc-freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-mvc-mustache</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-proxy-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet-portability</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-wadl-doclet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x-ban-custom-hk2-binding</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x-validation</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-weld2-se</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.rx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-rx-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.rx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-rx-client-guava</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.rx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-rx-client-java8</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.rx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-rx-client-jsr166e</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.rx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-rx-client-rxjava</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>html-json</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jettison</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-kryo</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>oauth1-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>oauth1-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>oauth1-signature</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>oauth2-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-util</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-external</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-jdk-http</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-jsr166e</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-apache-connector</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-grizzly-connector</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-jetty-connector</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${hk2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>${hk2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
            <version>${hk2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-locator</artifactId>
            <version>${hk2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies></dependencies>
```

This is the offending class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PAGE")
@XmlRootElement
public class Page implements Serializable {

    //... Id and other fields here

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(fetch = LAZY, mappedBy = "page")
    private Set<Activity> analyticsActivity;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have so many different JSON provider dependencies? You should remove all of them except for the Jackson one. Who knows which one will be the defaulted one if you have all of them on the classpath.

Comment: And in general, you have so many unnecessary dependencies. Seems you are maybe either a beginner in Jersey or in Maven. You need to understand the concept of _transitive_ dependencies. Some of the dependencies _pull in_ a lot of transitive dependencies. You have a lot of the transitive dependencies listed. It won't affect the project having them, but it makes it a whole lot cleaner _not_ having them.

Comment: And why do you have so many test framework providers? And so many containers? It almost seems like you have every possible Jersey dependency in your project. This is so unnecessary, confusing, and makes it difficult to figure out what is actually being used for for what. Take time to understand what the dependencies you are using are actually used for.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Thank you Paul. I am a beginner in Maven, though more experienced with Gradle so some of it translates. I joined this project with the dependencies already looking like this. If you think this is bad you should see the whole pom.xml, 174 dependencies. It's unfortunate that after I've expended the insight from my coworkers that I have to take issues with this monolith to SO; even if I can answer the question myself it's only useful for the few who work on similar poorly designed projects.

Comment: I didn't notice that everything was in `<dependencyManagement>`. I thought they were all in `<dependencies>`. The latter is what is actually used for the app. With that said, just FYI, you can get around adding all those Jersey dependencies to the `<dependencyManagement>` by using the `jersey-bom`. This will include everything you manually included. See [example](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-validate-return/blob/master/pom.xml#L34). What you should be showing us for your question, is the `<dependencies>`.

Answer (score 0):

A time ago I have the same problem annotation JsonIgnoreProperties is used on class scope. On jackson when you want ignore some field you need specify the field name.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true, value= {"prev", "next"})
public class Model implements Serializable {
    private Model prev;
    private Model next; ....
```

[Jackson Ignore Annotations example](https://www.concretepage.com/jackson-api/jackson-jsonignore-jsonignoreproperties-and-jsonignoretype)

To prevent "an infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)" make sure you dont have any reference, method calling a inside member, to prevent that you can ignore this fields too.
An example of "an infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)"

```
public class Model implements Serializable {
    private Model prev; // reference previous model
    private Model next; // reference next model
```

this type of data structure cause infinite recursion because always Jackson get prev or next field and get again and again and again.

Comment: Thank you for the response but the issue I'm having is that Jackson annotations have no effect on the JSON being generated. I went ahead and tested `@JsonIgnoreProperties` on the class but had no effect similarly to `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to this issue may unfortunately have nothing even to do with Jackson or Jersey. As someone stated "This is so unnecessary, confusing, and makes it difficult to figure out what is actually being used for for what." In my question I did not share the entire 174 dependency long pom.xml so it would've been impossible for anyone to answer this question. I hope someone finds this useful though.

When I added `@XmlTransient` to the field it made no positive difference. When I added it to the getter and the field I was able to hide the `analyticsActivity` from the produced JSON. I did not test if adding `@XmlTransient` to the getter alone is effective.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PAGE")
@XmlRootElement
public class Page implements Serializable {

    //... Id and other fields here

    @XmlTransient
    @OneToMany(fetch = LAZY, mappedBy = "page")
    private Set<Activity> analyticsActivity;

    @XmlTransient
    public Set<TmptREPDeskAnalytics> getAnalyticsActivity() {
        return analyticsActivity;
    }
}
```